# how sorting nullable number and ones is last

Tags: sql-server, sorting

my list something like this

| Id | Value | ِDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 2020 |
| 2 | 0 | 2022 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021 |
| 4 | 1 | 2023 |
| 5 | 100 | 2024 |
| 2 | 250 | 2018 |

I want to sort by column [Value] so that ones are at the end

The result should be as follows

| Id | Value | ِDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 2020 |
| 2 | 0 | 2022 |
| 5 | 100 | 2024 |
| 2 | 250 | 2018 |
| 4 | 1 | 2023 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021 |

I try

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY [Value] ASC , [Date] DESC
```

Comment: Eaither you expected output is wrong or query

Answer (score 1):

I defined a column named [Ones] and sorted the 1's to the end of the table and the problem was solved

```
SELECT [Id]
,[Value]
,[Date]
,(case WHEN Value = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ones]
FROM TABLE ORDER BY [Ones] ASC , [Value] ASC , [Date] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CASE** in the **ORDER BY** clause itself without using additional columns if you can specify an arbitrary value like **9999** which will be bigger than any other values in the column.

```
select * 
from table 
order by case when [value]=1 then 9999 else [value] end ,[Date] DESC ;
```